# Is my AJAX content already crawlable?

Tags: ajax, jquery, googlebot

I have build a site based on Ajax navigation.

I have build it that way, that whenever someone without javascript visits my site, the nav links, which usually load content via Ajax, are acting like normal links and the user can browse through the pages as usual.

Since, Google bot doesn't run javascript, it should theoretically be able to go through all links and corresponding sites as usual, right? Since they are valid links with the href tag pointed to the corresponding site.

Now I was wondering if thats sufficient or if I need to implant [this method from Google](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) too to make sure Google sees all my content?

Thanks for your insights and excuse my poor English!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can navigate your site by showing source (ctrl-u in chrome), google can also crawl your site. Yes, its that simple

Comment: Yeah I can do that. I already thought it will be fine for Google the way it is now, but i wanted to make sure :) Thanks!